# What causes buffering?

Tags: internet-connection, buffer

If I have a slow internet connection, what is normally the cause of buffering? In the example of a youtube video, why is there stop and start to my video's progress rather than just a slow developing amount of data?

Comment: Buffering is due to your slow internet connection.

Comment: @Moab I realize, but my question is more than that

Comment: Because it would be like playing a song and pausing and unpausing it several times a second where the breaks are significantly longer than the play duration. I don't think you want that.

Comment: Buffers are just storages of data offhand to be used at a later time. If YouTube is unable to fill the buffer faster than the player is emptying it, the player must stop and wait for more data to load into the buffer.

Comment: @Throsby your question is poorly written and only asks what is causing buffering, and I answered that. Question should be What is buffering and how does it work.